# get value of variable to another template

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

There are references I found in the internet about the passing of variable to other template. I tried to follow all the references but, I can't get the value that I need to populate. I have this xml file:

```
<Item>
   <Test>
      <ID>123345677</ID>
   </Test>
   <DisplayID>99884534</DisplayID>
</Item>
```

I need to populate MsgId element if the DisplayID is not null, else get value from the ID. My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="ID">
    <xsl:variable name="IDV" select="substring(.,0,35)"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DisplayID">
        <xsl:with-param name="IDP" select="$IDV"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="DisplayID">
    <xsl:param name="IDP"/>
    <xsl:element name="MsgId">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test=".!='' or ./*">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,0,35)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($IDP,0,35)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

The condition if DisplayID is not null is working, however, if I remove the value of DisplayID, there's no value getting from the ID. I don't know if I doing it correctly.

Your feedback is highly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "null". It could mean the element is not present at all, or it could mean the element has no string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

Demo for references : http://xsltransform.net/ejivdHb/16

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns1="http://locomotive/bypass/docx" >
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="Item">
    <xsl:element name="MsgId">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="DisplayID !='' ">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(DisplayID , 0 ,35)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring(Test/ID,0,35)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @hannah why this now not acceptable answer? You have xslt1.0 tagged as well?

Comment: Hi @TechBreak, sorry I didn't noticed your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is tagged XSLT 2.0, the match="Item" template from @TechBreak can be replaced by

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
    <MsgId>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring(
            if (DisplayId != '') 
            then DisplayID 
            else Test/ID, 1 ,35)"/>
    </MsgId>
</xsl:template>
```

(Note character counting starts from 1)